Is it possible to set up a socket over Bluetooth in React Native?
In Python I can do something like this
custom_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
custom_socket.bind((bluetooth_mac_address, port))

To use a socket over Bluetooth as if it was a TCP socket
Is it possible to do this in React Native?
I tried this
import TcpSocket from 'react-native-tcp-socket';

const connectToBluetoothServer = async (device: BluetoothDevice) => {
    try {
      console.log('Connecting to device with MAC address: E4:5F:01:D4:CA:CD');

      const options = {
        port: 11,
        host: device.address 
      };
      console.log('options ->', options);

      console.log('Actually attempting to create connection...');
      const client = TcpSocket.createConnection(options, () => {
        console.log('Connected to Bluetooth server');
        client.write('Hello World');
        console.log('Message sent: Hello World');
      });
      
      client.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('Data received: ', data.toString());
        client.destroy(); // Close the connection after receiving data
      });

      client.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('Connection error: ', error);
        Alert.alert('Connection Error', 'Failed to connect to the Bluetooth device. Please try again.');
      });

      client.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Connection closed');
      });
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.error('Error connecting to Bluetooth server: ', error);
      Alert.alert('Connection Error', 'Failed to connect to the Bluetooth device. Please try again.');
    }
  };

But I was getting errors that the MAC address is an invalid hostname
Connecting to device with MAC address: E4:5F:01:D4:CA:CD
options -> {"host": "E4:5F:01:D4:CA:CD", "port": 11}
Actually attempting to create connection...
Connection error:  Unable to resolve host "E4:5F:01:D4:CA:CD": No address associated with hostname
Connection closed


Sound like you need something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-native-bluetooth-serial
